# How can I set up a Ray (a distributed programming framework) and Flask app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ray

### Background

I've been trying, unsuccessfully, to implement Ray (https://github.com/ray-project/ray) into the production version of our AI API. Essentially, we want to use it to speed up one of our clustering algorithms to reduce the delays that occur with a large number of clusters. Our API is written using Python3.6, Flask, and Numpy. We use Elastic Beanstalk and bitbucket pipelines to make continuous development relatively easy. When we tried to incorporate Ray recently, though, we kept getting a series of errors. Some are build errors from EB which we fixed by deleting `enum34` (something we've never had to do before) and the rest have been what appear to be mod_wsgi errors (again, something we've never encountered before). The following is a snippet of the error messages recorded on CloudWatch (it repeats after this). I just want to know what I'm doing wrong, how to fix this error that's appearing, and how to deploy this API correctly.

### Stack Trace (from CloudWatch)

```
2020-09-15T02:27:57.571-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:26:06.609052 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 3248] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)

2020-09-15T02:27:57.571-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:26:06.623605 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 3248] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.

2020-09-15T02:27:57.571-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:26:06.623616 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 3248] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled

2020-09-15T02:27:57.571-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:26:06.624028 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3248] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor

2020-09-15T02:27:57.571-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:26:06.624068 2020] [:warn] [pid 3248] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.

2020-09-15T02:27:57.571-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:26:06.624072 2020] [:warn] [pid 3248] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.12.

2020-09-15T02:27:57.571-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:26:06.625952 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3248] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.12 configured -- resuming normal operations

2020-09-15T02:27:57.571-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:26:06.625967 2020] [core:notice] [pid 3248] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

2020-09-15T02:32:51.234-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:50.298983 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3248] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

2020-09-15T02:32:52.234-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:51.353642 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 7649] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)

2020-09-15T02:32:52.234-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:51.367142 2020] [so:warn] [pid 7649] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping

2020-09-15T02:32:52.234-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:51.368899 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 7649] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.

2020-09-15T02:32:52.234-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:51.368908 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 7649] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled

2020-09-15T02:32:52.234-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:51.369374 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 7649] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor

2020-09-15T02:32:52.234-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:51.369426 2020] [:warn] [pid 7649] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.

2020-09-15T02:32:52.234-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:51.369431 2020] [:warn] [pid 7649] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.12.

2020-09-15T02:32:52.234-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:51.377064 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7649] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.12 configured -- resuming normal operations

2020-09-15T02:32:52.234-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:51.377085 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7649] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638019 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] mod_wsgi (pid=7659): Callback registration for signal 15 ignored.

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638907 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "/opt/python/current/app/run.py", line 5, in <module>

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638917 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] import ray

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638925 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638931 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638937 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638942 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638948 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638954 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638957 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] from ray.worker import (

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638962 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638967 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638973 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638987 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638992 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.638998 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 873, in <module>

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.639001 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] ray.utils.set_sigterm_handler(sigterm_handler)

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.639006 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/utils.py", line 722, in set_sigterm_handler

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:54.639010 2020] [:warn] [pid 7659] signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.203215 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] DEBUG:ray.node:Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2020-09-15_09-32-55_202688_7659/logs.

2020-09-15T02:32:55.236-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.204027 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] INFO:ray.resource_spec:Starting Ray with 4.44 GiB memory available for workers and up to 2.24 GiB for objects. You can adjust these settings with ray.init(memory=<bytes>, object_store_memory=<bytes>).

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.309054 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] DEBUG:ray.services:Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:6379 to respond...

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.525174 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] DEBUG:ray.services:Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:19594 to respond...

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.526660 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] DEBUG:ray.services:Starting Redis shard with 0.8 GB max memory.

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.663605 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] INFO:ray.services:View the Ray dashboard at \x1b[1m\x1b[32mlocalhost:8265\x1b[39m\x1b[22m

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.665571 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] DEBUG:ray.node:Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2020-09-15_09-32-55_202688_7659/logs.

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.666148 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] DEBUG:ray.services:Determine to start the Plasma object store with 2.41 GB memory using /dev/shm.

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.670650 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] DEBUG:ray.services:Determine to start the Plasma object store with 2.41 GB memory using /dev/shm.

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.696353 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=7659): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/run.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.696417 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=7659): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/run.py'.

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.696594 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] Traceback (most recent call last):

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.696630 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] File "/opt/python/current/app/run.py", line 24, in <module>

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.696635 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] ray.init(configure_logging=False)

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.696643 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 806, in init

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.696648 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] job_id=job_id)

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.696654 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1178, in connect

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.696659 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] faulthandler.enable(all_threads=False)

2020-09-15T02:32:56.238-07:00   [Tue Sep 15 09:32:55.696677 2020] [:error] [pid 7659] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] AttributeError: 'mod_wsgi.Log' object has no attribute 'fileno
```

This is our code in .ebextensions:

### .ebextensions/packages.config file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    gcc-c++: []
    python36-devel: []
```

The actual error here seems to be `AttributeError: 'mod_wsgi.Log' object has no attribute 'fileno'`.

### .ebextensions/00_commands.config

```
commands:
  00_setup_pip:
    command: sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
  01_uninstall_enum34:
    command: pip uninstall -y enum34
```

### .ebextensions/00_files.config

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/00_uninstall_enum34.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      rm -f -r /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enum && rm -f -r /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enum34-1.1.10.dist-info
```

### run.py

For the Flask app, our run file is written as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import atexit
import importlib
import logging
import ray
import threading

import settings
import src.routes as routes
from src import app as application


# Commented out because we can't even get the single machine instance working. Forget clusters.
# if settings.ENVIRONMENT == 'PRODUCTION':
#     try:
#         ray.init(address='auto')
#     except Exception:
#         ray.init()
# else:
#     try:
#         ray.init()
#     except Exception as error:
#         raise error

ray.init(configure_logging=False)

# Import and register routes with Flask application
# importlib.import_module('.routes', 'src')
if settings.REPEAT:
    log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
    log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # If this service is designated as the repeat service this function will be called every hour.
    application.run('0.0.0.0', port=settings.PORT, debug=True, threaded=settings.THREADED)
```

We used to also have `container_commands` to start the Ray cluster but we've since removed that in order to just fix the single instance Ray problems we've encountered.

### bitbucket-pipeline.yaml

```
image: python:3.7.3

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          image: atlassian/default-image:2
          name: 'Build and Test'
          script:
            - zip -r careerfair-cluster-service.zip . -x '*.git*'
          # Define an artifact to pass the zip file to the next step
          artifacts:
            - careerfair-cluster-service.zip
      - step:
          image: python:3.7.3
          name: 'Deploy code to elasticbeanstalk'
          caches:
            - pip
          script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
            - pip install -U setuptools
            - pip install -U wheel
            - pip install -U flask-cors
            - pip install mod_wsgi-httpd
            - pip install -r requirements.txt
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.5.5
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-west-1'
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'careerfair-cluster-service'
                ENVIRONMENT_NAME: 'ClusterServiceProduction'
                ZIP_FILE: 'careerfair-cluster-service.zip'
                ENVIRONMENT: 'PRODUCTION'
                FLASK_APP_PATH: '/opt/python/current/app'
                PORT: 80
      - step:
          image: python:3.7.3
          name: 'Deploy code to elasticbeanstalk worker'
          caches:
            - pip
          script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
            - pip install -U setuptools
            - pip install -U wheel
            - pip install -U flask-cors
            - pip install mod_wsgi-httpd
            - pip install -r requirements.txt
            - rm -rf .platform
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.5.5
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-west-1'
                APPLICATION_NAME: 'careerfair-cluster-service'
                ENVIRONMENT_NAME: 'ClusterServiceRepeatWorker'
                ZIP_FILE: 'careerfair-cluster-service.zip'
                ENVIRONMENT: 'PRODUCTION'
                VERSION_LABEL: 'cluster-service-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER-repeater'
                FLASK_APP_PATH: '/opt/python/current/app'
                THREADED: 'False'
                PORT: 80
```

### wsgi.py

```
import sys


sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk is quite hard to debug. Many people have reported to have faced error out of the blue and could not track the cause down. If your application is running fine locally and you have it dockerized, why not try it with ECS, may be Fargate?

Comment: This is a bit of a non-answer, but Ray has a built-in elastic serving solution that you could consider. https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/serve/index.html

Comment: Does Ray serve support variables in the route like Flask does (i.e. `/this/is/route/<id>`)? I can't find any documentation on that. At this point I'm willing to try switching entirely to Ray since we're pretty stumped and can't do much about the Flask/Ray issue stated above. The route variables are necessary since our other services use this.

Comment: Also, we're using elastic beanstalk because we wanted to reduce the hassle involved with deploying our resources. We could use ECS but right now we're pretty set on keeping our existing infrastructure.